# Selecting a row from a particular column datatable without LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

My DataTable has the columns - Id, Name, Address. I need to select the column Address only WHERE ID = 7. How do I do this ? No LINQ please.

I was thinking of this -

```
DataView view = new DataView(MyDataTable);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
Now you can select.

DataRow[] myRows = distinctValues.Select();
//Get the desired answer by iterating myRows.
```

Is there a simpler way ?

thanks.

Comment: @Selman22 - because I don't know linq right now.

Comment: without being glib, it's time to learn. there are loads of examples out there on the web. linq is very powerful and has both 'all method' and 'semi sql' approaches that will serve your purposes. jump in. you will float.

Comment: @horace - yes, but I want to see if there is a easy non-linq way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't want to use `LINQ`, you can use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "ColumnA");
var myRows = new List<DataRow>();
foreach(DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
{
   if(row["Id"].ToString() == "7") myRows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: just fyi: this is much slower than a straight linq implementation.